# Can I capture only a particular colour with a Canon 650D?

Tags: canon, dslr, black-and-white, special-effects, selective-color

I have a **Canon DSLR 650D**, and I want to know if there are any settings or features in the camera that will only catch/accept the predefined color. For example, I just want to capture only red color and everything else should be B/W.

Please don't suggest Adobe Photoshop — I want to do this in-camera.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but I just want to add the _reason_ this is best done on a computer later. This effect must include a definition of how broad a color range to emphasize — does red-orange count, or only precisely pure red (which rarely exists in nature). It is hard to see the effect of tuning this on a small camera LCD.

Answer (score 1):

The effect you want is called "selective color" and most cameras can't do in-camera (and I personally think this is a good thing, but that's just my opinion).

You do need to do it in post processing, you don't have to use Photoshop, there are many image editors that can do this, some of them are even free (for example GIMP)

Comment: Thanks for your time.But I think like Blurring techniques in cameras this feature is also available as I am unaware of it..lets see anyone else answer it :)

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui - from what I can find on the net the "creative filters" feature is only available in the 700D and later - and even then it doesn't include a selective color filter - so sorry but you can't do it in-camera

Answer (score 1):

The Canon 650D/Rebel T4i does not include the capability to do *selective color* in-camera. Several Canon compact digital cameras offered the feature. The Nikon D5100 is an SLR that includes the capability for selective color via in-camera processing after the image is captured via the *Retouch* menu.

Comment: What is the best feature of Canon 650D/Rebel T4i that you will suggest. I know its off topic

Comment: Touchscreen, compatibility to STM lenses and video. first canon slr that can auto focus while video recording. I just wish 650D came with a copy of angry birds. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do advanced manipulation like that in camera.  In general, most DSLRs are limited to relatively simple or special stuff like limited HDR processing, simple B/W or basic cropping.  Advanced editing like selective coloration require post production work and often require some matte painting to get it to work the way you want.  It doesn't have to be Photoshop, something like GIMP could also do it, but you can't do it in camera.

Comment: FWIW quite a few DSLRs _do_ have such a feature, but I agree that it's best done on a computer for the reasons you give.

Comment: Actually I think this particular effect is best not done at all, but that's a different issue. :)